# List of Objects with int property compared to List of Int

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have 2 lists. First is a list of objects that has an int property ID. The other is a list of ints.

I need to compare these 2 lists and copy the objects to a new list with only the objects that matches between the two lists based on ID. Right now I am using 2 foreach loops as follows:

```
var matched = new list<Cars>();
foreach(var car in cars)
foreach(var i in intList)
{
 if (car.id == i) 
  matched.Add(car);
}
```

This seems like it is going to be very slow as it is iterating over each list many times. Is there way to do this without using 2 foreach loops like this?

Comment: Could you have duplicate ints? Could you have duplicate cars with the same ID? What should be done in such cases?

Comment: I will never have duplicates in either list, no.

Comment: Then I'd be suggesting something very close to Jamiec's answer using a `HashSet<int>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One slow but clear way would be

```
var matched = cars.Where(car => intList.Contains(car.id)).ToList();
```

You can make this quicker by turning the `intList` into a dictionary and using `ContainsKey` instead.

```
var intLookup = intList.ToDictionary(k => k);
var matched = cars.Where(car => intLookup.ContainsKey(car.id)).ToList();
```

Even better still, a `HashSet`:

```
var intHash = new HashSet(intList);
var matched = cars.Where(car => intHash.Contains(car.id)).ToList();
```

Comment: even better yet a a HashSet

Comment: Hashset and dictionary would be much elegant.Upvoted.

Comment: Rect: `HashSet<int>`. The type can't be inferred here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some simple `linq` something like this should work:

```
var matched = cars.Where(w => intList.Contains(w.id)).ToList();
```

this will take your list of cars and then find only those items where the id is contained in your intList.